# Google analytics not finding tracking script on asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I have this code in my master page in the head section:

```
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="830gFtORfJaVYXiLQ6EVfCNoiMW3zyn2DVS7L1zbr20" />
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-23254350-2']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';   
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 
        'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

   </script>
   </head>
```

The problem is that google analytics is not seeing the tracking script. Any ideas?

Comment: How long are you waiting to see results? It can take up to 24 hours for Google Analytics to process.

Comment: Other things to check: Make sure you are using the right account number.  Make sure the profile you are looking at doesn't have any filters on it that would cause your hits to be excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually find that the tracking status updates pretty quickly after a page has been viewed and the tracking beacon has been sent.

You should go to the homepage of the site where this is installed and check that the JavaScript code is present in the page source in case the asp code has removed it somehow.

If it's there then you should use something like the Firefox Live HTTP Headers addon check that a request for an image called `__utm.gif` is being made to Google Analytics.

If that's all OK but the status is still not updated you could try checking that you've entered the correct account number into the tracking code.

Comment: I checked for the __utm.gif call and it's being made. Does this mean that it's working even if analytics can't pick it up yet?

Comment: In my experience, general page views do come "fairly quickly" - anywhere from 1-4 hours, but Google officially states 24 hours.  So again, how long have you actually waited to check?